# Reference for (general case) of uniqueness of singular value decomposition (SVD)

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, matrix-analysis, singular-values, uniqueness-theorems

My statistics research requires me to understand the non-uniqueness of SVD in the degenerate case of repeated singular values.

I believe that the statements and proofs on this StackExchange posts are correct https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/644327/how-unique-are-u-and-v-in-the-singular-value-decomposition/4203355#4203355. This claims uniqueness is up to unitary transformations within the spaces of repeated singular values (my intuition being that it is most natural to think of SVD as a sum of partial isometries).

However, I would like a published reference to cite in my work. The (many) standard matrix analysis texts I tried only ever prove uniqueness in the case of distinct singular values (which is up to complex phase multiplications).

Does anyone know of an appropriate reference for this?

Answer (score 2):

A singular value decomposition $A=U \Sigma V^T$ may not be unique. And the reason is not only the fact that we can reorder the singular values $\sigma_i$ on the diagonal of $\Sigma$. If the matrix is $A$ is singular, then $range(A^*)$ may have a non-trivial orthogonal complement, and hence the left singular vectors in $ker(T)$ can be chosen in many ways. Even in infinitely many ways, and so some matrices may even have infinitely many singular value decompositions.

Please see **Exercise E.38.4** and its solution in:
http://bit.ly/LinAlgebra

I included that exercise in my lecture notes (the link above) because my students asked this question repeatedly.

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation with that book in your post. This is mandatory per the site rules.

Comment: Dear Mr. Polini, I apologize for not mentioning that these are my lecture notes. Now I  added that notice in the post. If something else need to be altered, please kindly let me know.

Comment: Thanks for including that notice!